# Using closures in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a jquery plugin to attach events and event handlers at run time:

The HTML:

```
<table id="digitalInputsTable">
<thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Value</th>
    <th>State</th>
    <th>Enabled</th>
    <th>Polarity</th>
    <th>Ignore Reset</th>       
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>      
        <td>
            <span class="">Name1</span>     
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="">0</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span class="">Normal</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="" jqmon="0" jqreg="0" id="digitalInputsTable_checkbox_03">
        </td>
        <td>
            <select class="" jqmon="0" jqreg="0" id="digitalInputsTable_select_04">
                <option value="0=Alarm">0=Alarm</option>
                <option value="1=Alarm">1=Alarm</option>
            </select>     
        </td>
        <td>          
            <input type="checkbox" value="true" class="" jqmon="0" jqreg="0" id="digitalInputsTable_checkbox_05">       
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The Data Structure:

```
$("#digitalInputsTable").bindEvents({
    parentControl: "digitalInputsTable",
    controls: [
        {   
            id: undefined, 
            name: "checkbox", 
            idStartsWith: "digitalInputsTable_checkbox_",               
            event: "click", 
            callbackHandler: "checkboxCallback"             
        },
        {
            id: undefined,
            name: "checkbox",
            idStartsWith: "digitalInputsTable_checkbox_",
            event: "blur",
            callbackHandler: "blurCallback"
        },
        {
            id: undefined,
            name: "select", 
            idStartsWith: "digitalInputsTable_select_",                 
            event: "change", 
            callbackHandler: "selectCallback"               
        }
    ]   
});
```

The Plugin:

```
$.fn.bindEvents = function(options) {           
for(var i = 0; i < options.controls.length; i++) {      
    var control = options.controls[i];
    switch(control.name) {
        case "checkbox":
            control.name = ":checkbox";
            break;          
    }

    if(control.id) {
        // find control by ID.
        // Attach event to the control.
    }
    else if(control.idStartsWith) {         
        $("#" + options.parentControl).find(control.name + "[id^=" + control.idStartsWith + "]")
                                    .bind(control.event, function(e) {                                          
                                        function(ctrl) {                                                
                                            eval(ctrl.callbackHandler + "();");
                                        };                                          
                                    }(control));
    }
};
```

};

The Problem:
When I check the check box, I am not able to call the "checkboxCallback" callback function of the check box. May be I am using closure incorrectly. Please advise.

Comment: please add a little more info: what effect does `control.name=":checkbox"` have? From looks of it, youre trying something similar to `$('*:checkbox')` which will return nothing, instead i would go `$('*[type=\"checkbox\"]')` - which would only work with elements with the argument 'type' present (inputs)

Comment: Actually this is what I am trying to do: $("#parentTableID).find(":checkbox").bind("click", function() {...}); The :checkbox here acts as a pseudoselector

Comment: ah my bad; `$(':checkbox') is equivalent to $('[type=checkbox]')` but then - would the [type=checkbox][id^="someidstart"] work? I'd make sure that there in fact is a set of nodes to call the .bind chain on

Comment: Yes mschr, that would work. :checkbox psuedo selector is just a shortcut to what you have mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer, but it should point you in the right direction. Basically when you loop over the `options.controls` and need to perform actions on them in the future, you need to use a closure to separate them.

```
$.fn.bindEvents = function(options) {
    // loop through the controls
    for (var i = 0, control; control = options.controls[i]; ++i) {
        // close over the current item
        (function(ctrl) {
            // you can safely use ctrl now

            // call the callback like so
            ctrl.callbackHandler();
        }(control));
    }
};
```

Btw, don't use `eval` to call the callback, just pass the function reference:

```
callbackHandler: checkboxCallback
```

I've added example of how to call it inside the `$.fn.bindEvents` function.

Comment: Thanks Jack for the reply. Things seems to be working fine except that the browser is not recognizing the ctrl.callbackHandler() as the valid method. The "callbackHandler" is a property and not a method.

Comment: Because you passed the handler as string instead of object. My guess.

Comment: Yes Jack, that is true. The handler is being passed as a string. Buts that the kind of ease I want my javascript+jquery developer mates to have. It seems eval is a good option too. Do you see any browser related disadvantage (although I know its not a good practice) using "eval"?

Comment: Jack, your direction was enough for pointing me to my destination. I can rest in peace now :). Thanks a lot. Good day.

Comment: Btw instead of eval you can do window[ctrl.callbackHandler]()

Comment: Thanks Jack, I'll try this at my end.